# «Cuidar que ...» vs «Cuidar de que ...»

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, preposiciones, subordinadas, queísmo-dequeísmo

The dictionary entry for ***cuidar*** shows uses of it both with and without ***de***:

> [**cuidar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bbp9xqI)
>
> 1. tr. Poner diligencia, atención y solicitud en la ejecución de algo.
> 2. tr. Asistir, guardar, conservar. *Cuidar a un enfermo, la casa, la ropa.* U. t. c. intr. *Cuidar DE la hacienda, DE los niños.*

The difference being that ***cuidar*** allows for a direct object, while ***cuidar de*** does not.

How does this apply when using it with subordinate expressions? Like this:

> Cuida que no se te moje el pantalón.
> Cuida de que no se te moje el pantalón.

Are those two sentences equally correct? Do they mean exactly the same or are there any slight differences in connotation?

Comment: Por el artículo del DPD sobre [cuidar(se)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=WXiA8Czg0D6Hq4M3o7) me da toda la sensación de que _cuida que no se te moje_ es incorrecto: _Cuando el complemento es un infinitivo o una oración subordinada introducida por que, significa ‘procurar que se lleve a cabo la acción expresada por el verbo subordinado’. En ambos casos el complemento debe ir precedido de la preposición de_.

Comment: @fedorqui ostras, pues yo habría dicho que en ese caso "cuidar" se entiende en su primera acepción, y sería sin "de": "cuida que no se te moje el pantalón" (pon diligencia y atención para que no se te moje), que sería lo mismo que "vigila que no se te moje", que también lo escribiría sin "de".

Comment: @Charlie ¿lo mismo es que de tanto decirlo hemos perdido la versión inicial? Como si lo correcto de inicio fuera _Cuida(do), [COMA] que no se te moje_

Comment: @fedorqui pues igual. Buscando en Google "cuida que" y "cuida de que", hay casi 20 veces más resultados de lo segundo que de lo primero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this article on [*queísmo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que%C3%ADsmo) and [*dequeísmo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que%C3%ADsmo), the standard form for introducing a subordinate clause is *cuidar **de** que*, and excluding it is an example of queísmo:

> **Cuidar [algo o a alguien] y cuidar DE algo o alguien.** El verbo cuidar presenta dos regímenes: complemento de régimen de grupos nominales introducido por la preposición *de* y con complemento directo, es decir, sin dicha preposición.
>
> a) Cuida del niño.
>
> b) Cuida al niño.
>
> No obstante, delante de la conjunción subordinante *que* solo es posible el complemento de régimen, por lo que la ausencia de dicha preposición sería queísmo
>
> a) *Cuida que no entre nadie en el jardín. / Cuida de que no entre
>   nadie en el jardín.
>
> - [*QUEÍSMO Y DEQUEÍSMO*](http://asociaciondecorrectores.org.pe/2do_encuentro/queismo_y_dequeismo-p_jimenez.pdf), Pamela Jiménez Lizama

both sentences have the same meaning, but one is indicative of a certain prescriptively incorrect style of speech (/hypercorrection), analogous to instances of leísmo.

Comment: Cuidar *que* (sin *de*) es la única forma que he visto cuando el significado es *pensar* (3.ª acepción), **cuido que** el DPD se ha equivocado.

Answer (score 3):

El artículo del DPD sobre [cuidar(se)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=WXiA8Czg0D6Hq4M3o7) dice que efectivamente en el sentido de *cuidar a alguien o algo* tiene dos opciones:

- como transitivo, se usa *cuidar*.
- como intransitivo, se usa *cuidar de*.

Luego, y en lo que parece que sería la respuesta a tu pregunta, habla de su uso en infinitivo o subordinada, indicando que lo correcto es utilizar *cuidar de*:

> 2. Cuando el complemento es un infinitivo o una oración subordinada introducida por *que*, significa ‘procurar que se lleve a cabo la acción expresada por el verbo subordinado’. En ambos casos el complemento debe ir precedido de la preposición *de*: *«Hacían sus adquisiciones y cambalaches con calma, cuidando de sacar el máximo rendimiento a la propina de papá Telmo»* (Delibes Madera [Esp. 1987]); *«Cuando salía, [...] cuidando de que no lo viera ni su cochero, le daba la plata para los gastos»* (GaMárquez Amor [Col. 1985]).

Por tanto solo una de tus frases sería correcta:

- <s>Cuida que no se te moje el pantalón.</s>
- ***Cuida de que*** no se te moje el pantalón.

A mí en España no me suena nada mal la otra frase, pero supongo que porque coloquialmente hemos ido acortando el *cuidado, que no se te vaya a mojar el pantalón* a un *cuida* sin coma posterior. Pero eso es una hipótesis mía que debería contrastar un poco.

Comment: Y quizás también se relaciona con *Vigila que no se te vaya a mojar el pantalón.*